# Do I really need a container for my rows and cols to work correctly? (bootstrap v5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My question is simple:
Do I need a container for rows and cols to work correctly?
right now I'm not using a container in the parent elements which contains two rows and the first row has some cols in it. right now in the website i didn't use a container, and it's working fine [here](https://dsnp.ir/salesexperts.html) (or at least I think so)

```
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <% if (experts.length>0){ %>
                <% for (let expert of experts) { %>
            <div class="sales-wrapper mt-5">
                <div class="row m-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-3">
                        <div class="sales-img"><img src=" <%= expert.imageurl  %> " alt="<%= expert.name  %>"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-7">
                        <p><%= expert.name %> </p>
                        <div><i class="fa-solid fa-phone-flip ms-2"></i><p class="d-inline-block"><%= expert.phone  %></p></div>
                        <div><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope ms-2"></i><p class="d-inline-block"><%= expert.mail  %></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-2">
                        <div class="sales-social"><a href="<% if (expert.telegramurl){%><%=expert.telegramurl %><% } else{ %> # <%} %>"> <img src="/assets/img/Telegram.png" alt=""> </a></div>
                        <div class="sales-social"><a href="<% if (expert.whatsappurl){%><%=expert.whatsappurl %><% } else{ %> # <%} %>"> <img src="/assets/img/Whatsapp.png" alt=""> </a></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-0">
                <p class="pt-3 text-justify"><%=expert.description%></p>
            </div>
            </div>    

            <% } } else{%>
                <div class="display5"> هیچ کارشناسی یافت نشد!!!</div>
            <% } %>
            
        </div>
```

but I read in the [documents of the bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/) that I should add a container. so maybe something like this :

```
        <div class="content-wrapper *container*">
            <% if (experts.length>0){ %>
                <% for (let expert of experts) { %>
            <div class="sales-wrapper mt-5">
                <div class="row m-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-3">
                        <div class="sales-img"><img src=" <%= expert.imageurl  %> " alt="<%= expert.name  %>"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-7">
                        <p><%= expert.name %> </p>
                        <div><i class="fa-solid fa-phone-flip ms-2"></i><p class="d-inline-block"><%= expert.phone  %></p></div>
                        <div><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope ms-2"></i><p class="d-inline-block"><%= expert.mail  %></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-2">
                        <div class="sales-social"><a href="<% if (expert.telegramurl){%><%=expert.telegramurl %><% } else{ %> # <%} %>"> <img src="/assets/img/Telegram.png" alt=""> </a></div>
                        <div class="sales-social"><a href="<% if (expert.whatsappurl){%><%=expert.whatsappurl %><% } else{ %> # <%} %>"> <img src="/assets/img/Whatsapp.png" alt=""> </a></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-0">
                <p class="pt-3 text-justify"><%=expert.description%></p>
            </div>
            </div>    

            <% } } else{%>
                <div class="display5"> هیچ کارشناسی یافت نشد!!!</div>
            <% } %>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap, using a container or a container-fluid is generally recommended to wrap your content. These containers provide a consistent and responsive layout for your web page. The container class sets a fixed width for the content, and the container-fluid class sets the width to 100% of the viewport.

While your current code might work fine without a container, it's not considered a best practice to omit it, especially when using Bootstrap. The container helps in creating responsive layouts and ensures that the content is centered and properly aligned on different screen sizes and devices.

Without a container, your content might appear flush against the edges of the browser window, and it may not adjust well on smaller screens, causing horizontal scrolling and other layout issues.

To add a container to your existing code, you can simply add the "container" class to the "content-wrapper" div like this:

```html
<div class="content-wrapper container">
    <!-- Your existing content here -->
</div>
```

If you prefer a full-width layout, you can use "container-fluid" instead:

```html
<div class="content-wrapper container-fluid">
    <!-- Your existing content here -->
</div>
```

By doing so, you ensure that your layout will behave as expected across different devices, and it will align with Bootstrap's responsive design principles.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. well i guess i have to use the container class in the end.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT